# Facebook web SDK writing css to page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add the Facebook JavaScript SDK to my project.
I followed the instructions here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

I added the init script in the `<body>` as instructed and it connects fine but, the SDK adds a `<style>` element that writes all of FBs style code to my page.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf8"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/flex.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bundle.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
            appId            : 'myAppID',
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v2.12'
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
</body>
```

Below is how it turns out:

[image]

Comment: what server are you using and how exactly?

Comment: I did not see where you can choose which server you pull this from but, the SDK is being loaded from https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js.

Comment: i mean YOUR server. the one that runs on port 8887.